# Wordpress Posts Redirect to a new folder

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have created a new site with the same post structure of the old one and I would like to redirect all the posts from the old to the new one.

`The old site is something like:`
http://www.website.com/site1/

`And the new site is something like:`
http://www.website.com/site2/

Same domain.

The folder and post structure are the same. So a sample posts on site 1 (http://www.website.com/site1/post1/) would be redirected to site 2 (http://www.website.com/site2/post1/).

How can I redirect all posts on my htaccess?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by this rewrite rule:

```
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^site1/(.*)$ /site2/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

If you don't want external redirect (no change of URL in browser) then remove `R` flag: